# Simple JavaScript not working when changing color in the body

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015, multi-device-hybrid-apps

when watching this [tutorial](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/cross-platform-development-with-visual-studio), I tried to repro the JavaScript used in the beginning.

However when setting up the function

```js
        function setRandomColor(e) 
        {
            var bodyElement = document.querySelector("body");
            bodyElement.style.background.Color = "yellow";
        }
```

the part

```js
bodyElement.style.background.Color = "yellow";
```

does not run, simply because style is not shown as an option.

Per my reseach this is supposed to work. Therefore my question: Is this a bug or what?

Note that I am using Visual Studio 2015 with Apache Cordova, version 14.0.22609.0 (CTP6, I believe).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to w3schools, the background attribute you are calling is not supported in HTML5.

To correctly call the background color, try:

```html
bodyElement.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
```

For more information:[w3schools explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_body.asp)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However I wonder why .style was not available as an option when writing the code...

Comment: This could be a hiccup in the editor you use. I would recommend using PHPStorm, as it is a solid, widely used editor for HTML/CSS, JavaScript and other languages.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
bodyElement.style.backgroundColor
```